# Can I return an anonymous closure in JRuby when an interface is expected?

Tags: java, interface, jruby

Per [the docs](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby), I can pass a block to a method that expects an interface, and the block will be converted to an anonymous implementation of that interface.  It's pretty cool!

However, I have a Ruby subclass of a Java class, which has a method that's supposed to *return* something that implements an interface.

```
// Java
public abstract class Parent {
  public MyInterface getIt();
}
```

```
# Ruby
class Child < Parent
  def getIt
    # Need to return an implementation of MyInterface?
  end
end
```

I have tried making a `Proc` and a `lambda`, but neither of those work.  I can add a method to the Parent (in Java) that forces automatic conversion

```
protected MyInterface passThrough(MyInterface mi) { return mi; }
```

and then this works:

```
def getIt
  passThrough {|thing|
    puts thing.inspect
  }
end
```

This seems really hacky though.  Is this just an oversight in how JRuby works, or am I missing some alternate solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes - you should be able to do just that ... just use `to_java` on a proc/lambda :

```
class Child < Parent
  def getIt
    lambda { |*args| puts args.inspect }.to_java(Java::MyInterface)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

than of course there's always the "crazy" java-way with `Proxy` :

```
class Child < Parent
  def getIt
    loader = JRuby.runtime.jruby_class_loader # or java_class' loader
    ifaces = [ MyInterface.java_class ].to_java Java::JavaLang::Class
    Java::JavaLangReflect::Proxy.newProxyInstance(loader, ifaces) do 
      |proxy, method, args| puts "#{method} #{args.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

uber-complicated but it kind of uses an anonymous closure to implement the interface :)